# Testing condition whether input is a character in c++

Tags: function, if-statement, visual-c++, char, return-value

I'm writing a function which is supposed to convert any user entered uppercase letter into its lowercase equivalent while also returning any non-character value unchanged. I'm using the formula:
`ch = input + 32;`  to convert uppercase to lowercase but I'm unsure about how to set a condition to test if input is a letter.

Answer (score 0):

Use standard function `isalpha()` from `<ctype.h>`